# Button onClick doesn't work

Tags: android, button, android-button, android-viewpager

I made a viewPager with three layouts on every page... And i want to deal with a button on second page, but somehow i cannot... (P.S.: without button codes, my viewPager works) I just simply try to change background when clicked...

Here's my codes:

```
public class ViewPagerProjectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);


}


public void OnClick(View v) {
    if(v.equals(btn)) {
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.deneme2);
            l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
    }       
}    
}
```

And Here's the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yahya.ViewPagerProject/com.yahya.ViewPagerProject.ViewPagerProjectActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.yahya.ViewPagerProject.ViewPagerProjectActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
```

Comment: What's in your layout file for the ViewPager?

Comment: on every layouts there are something else... on second there's just a button, which i want to do click with.

Comment: what is the line number? and probably you should make it like LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)ViewPagerProjectActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);

Comment: post your layout file please.

Comment: The answer which meltemyldrim's given has solved problem, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try these lines, i hope it works...

```
View deneme2lout = (View) getView.inflate(R.layout.deneme2,null);
btn = (Button) deneme2lout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
public class ViewPagerProjectActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {               

             l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now compiler gives me a NullPointerException error on this line "btn.setOnClickListener( ... );"

Comment: I'm getting still NullPointerException ... I can't figure out why?  :/

Comment: Have you tried whole code as i gave in my answer? dont use that onClicl() outside onCreate() as you do in your question.

Comment: Yeap, i did... still gives me that.

Comment: Strange!That shouldn't.using this code,you don't need to implement onClickListener.Remove it if you did that.But i think,you already got the answer so not a problem now!!

Comment: Except "NullPointerException", yes i got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You want viewPager or the xml codes which contains the button ?

Comment: I figure out why that is... Because i'm on main.xml but the button is on another xml file... But the problem is i'm using the viewPager, so it fill the context with the layouts, and i've got no idea about where should i write this button onClick???

Comment: Please post your xml as well as your code.then i can help you on the same!

Comment: I've change the position of the codes, and it worked. Problem's solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
> btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

This does not work because `ViewPagerProjectActivity`  does not have the required

`implements OnClickListener` interface

Comment: You're right, i just forget about it... But now it's done and compiler gives me a NullPointerException erron on this line "btn.setOnClickListener(this);" but why? :/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 public class ViewPagerProjectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener

 then btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this sort of problem when i add a custom UI element to an XML file..

I just removed that particular item from Xml file and build the project and again reverted the file. Problem got solved. Looks crazy..But just try once.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to handle a button's click you have two options

1. In the xml layout file set android:onClick to something like "myButtonClick". Then in your related Activity .java file in which your going to use this layout have a method `public void myButtonClick(View v)`. Then put your logic there.
2. In your onCreate() put

   ```
   btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {               

        //Your logic here
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you out..

to use buttons in android...

map the button in XML file with Button in java class file as...

```
Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.layout.button_id_in_your_xml);
```

next.. call the onclickListener for the button bt as follows..

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //write what you want to do when you click the button
}
);
```